# How to deal segmentation fault with GDB under particular circumstance?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I wrote a C program on linux to process large amount of data. It seemed working OK most of the time, but I met a segmentation fault error when doing a job. Because the program works OK with other data so I don't know how to deal with this problem. And by the way how to retrieve variable value when segfault occurred?

here is the gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
tyn_p4d_encode32 (in=0x10000000c01, cnt_in=118248, out=0x10000000101 <Address 0x10000000101 out of bounds>, add_termination=1) at tyn_coder.c:645
645                         length_stat[count_bits32(*(in + i)) - 1]++;     
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.14.90-24.fc16.6.x86_64 zlib-1.2.5-5.fc16.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  tyn_p4d_encode32 (in=0x10000000c01, cnt_in=118248, out=0x10000000101 <Address 0x10000000101 out of bounds>, add_termination=1) at tyn_coder.c:645
#1  0x0000000000404582 in nodes_term32_flush (array=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>, nodes_context=0x2ded020, is_last=0) at tyn_indexer.c:116
#2  0x0000000000407b78 in tyn_exsorter_sort (exsorter=0x64c4a0, context=0x2ded020, nodes_flush=0x404320 <nodes_term32_flush>, progress_callback=0x404190 <progress_callback>) at tyn_exsorter.c:131
#3  0x0000000000406ddf in tyn_build_index (tyn_config=0x61a060, index_name=0x4138d1 "mysql_index") at tyn_indexer.c:731
#4  0x0000000000403850 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at tyn_indexer.c:943
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile and link with `-g` flag to be able to use debugger; but you seem already to be doing that.  `print` (abbreviated `p`) prints variable value; `bt`, `up`, `down`, `frame` are other useful commands.  Otherwise, `help` within gdb or `info gdb`.

Comment: `$1 = <optimized out>`  how to make this not optimized out?

Comment: @MickeyShine You must compile without optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the coredump in this case. First of all enable coredumps `ulimit -c unlimited`...the use gdb like this `gdb <path to executable> <path to coredump>`...this coredump at the time of the segfault will contain the values of the variables and frames etc intact....so u can use this information for debugging purposes.